# Customizing Outlook Navigation Pane and Forms Outlook 2010

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, ms-office, customization

I have two main issues I am trying to address and after a while searching haven't found what I need to achieve. I have created a custom Outlook AddIn to show information hosted outside of Outlook and Exchange. I can get that working and showing forms but the customer wants tighter integration.

Ideally I want something that shows up in the Navigation Pane like the way the SharePoint AddIn for document libraries does. In that I need to enumerate a treeview based upon results from a WCF call then when the user clicks on an item it opens that and displays entirely custom information retrieved from the WCF service. I have no issue creating the controls and displaying the data but I'm not an outlook specialist. So the key to the question is how do I get the items into the navigation pane (I assume I use the Solutions Module) and then show my form in the right hand side with my data from the WCF?

I have looked all around custom message classes, form regions etc but I don't seem to be able to make sense of that as the items I want to show in the right hand pane don't relate to Outlook message classes.

I can see that I can create a custom task pane and could do the tree view there but don't really want to go down that route. Also I don't want to spring for the AddIn Express stuff as this is just a prototype at the present time.

Sorry for the wordy question but I'm at a dead end.

Comment: Can you maybe include a screenshot/mockup of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Well, you maybe know this, but I would look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692173%28v=office.14%29.aspx for further ideas. As long as the explanation of the desired layout and functionality stays without any more info, this would be the most far I can go in this point. I have made some Outlook Addin in past and played with menus, but hard to say more, as the question is not so specific.

Comment: Hi Mico, I have seen that and used the idea it's close to what I was looking for but not close enough. We have decided to use a custom task pane instead now and will go with that solution. We may revisit this in the new year.

Comment: Hi John, we have decided on a compromise solution using Custom Task Panes so I'm going to let this question lapse. I'll revisit in the new year.

Comment: It sounds like you "might" need to create a custom MAPI provider.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842153.aspx

Comment: I've a sort of solution that might fit your needs. But I developed it with C# Add-in Express.

Basically what it does is, adding folders from an SQL Database into the navigation pane and if a folder is expanded it retreives the next layer of folders from the Database. When a folder already exists it does nothing. 

It's achievable but not recommended. It takes alot of time to figure it out how to do it. I'm still searching for some sort of plugin like you need aswell. But it seems dat Microsoft protected Outlook from developers developing plugins like that..........